# how to send telnet command like putty does?

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Hello I need help with sending telnet client 
everything is working fine with connecting and receiving server messages but when I send any command like help to the telnet server I don't get the telnet help message maybe there is problem with my script:

```
using System.Text;

static NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);

byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("help");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

`default` operation for classes uses `null` value, so this:

```
default(NetworkStream)
```

is always equal to `null`. You need to initialize your stream properly [with a socket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) you want to connect to:

```
using (serverStream = new NetworkStream(mySocket))
{
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("help");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();
}
```